# How to generate report for sonarQube6.7

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to generate report using SonarQube6.7.
I tried using sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4 plugin, sonar server started - but while running sonar-scanner throws,

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:`org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getConfiguration()Lorg/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration;"`
```

error.

How can i get a report????

Answer (score 0):

[You can download report plugin here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+Plugin)

and add it to sonarqube_folde/extensions/plugins/

If you have older version you can Click on "More versions" under *By SonarSource – SonarSource – Issue Tracker – Supported by SonarSource*

Note: You have to buy Enterprise license

Answer (score 0):

As @George312 alludes, the [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/) gives you the ability to produce (and have automatically emailed) PDFs of your Portfolio homepages. I suspect that's not what you're after.

There is no functionality compatible with modern SonarQube versions which will generate PDF reports of project homepages or any other (non-Portfolio) portion of the interface or data.

However, web services are available to extract data from your instance. You'll find a link to the on-board Web API documentation in the footer of each page. Once you've extracted the data you should presumably be able to construct your reports.